# FLASH - check if a Text input is empty or not

Tags: forms, flash, validation

This is my first time doing an FLASH form validation and I'm new to FLASH.
I have the follow Actions: (AS 2.0)

```
bSubmit.onRelease = function() 
{
      valiForm();
}
function valiForm()
{
     var sMessage = "Name: " + tName.text + "\nE-mail: " + tEmail.text + "\nPhone: " + tPhone.text;
     lvSend = new LoadVars();
     lvReply = new LoadVars();
     var thanks = "Thanks " + tName.text + "your message has been sent";
     lvSend.msg = sMessage;
     lvSend.address = "myemail@ex.ex";
     tName.text = "";
     tEmail.text = "";
     tPhone.text = "";
     lvReply.onLoad()
     {
        tDone.text = thanks;
     }
     lvSend.sendAndLoad('/templates/t3976/mail.php', lvReply, 'POST');
}
```

now before I send the form I want to check if the `tName` field is empty if it is alert of some way and if it's good then submit the form. also I want do to the same for the `nPhone` field.

thanks for the help and sorry for my bas english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the simplest way is to compare String in IF

```as
if(tName.text != ""){
    // proceed form code here
}
```

in your case that would be

```
bSubmit.onRelease = function() 
{
      valiForm();
}
function valiForm()
{
   if(tName.text != "" && tPhone.text != ""){
     var sMessage = "Name: " + tName.text + "\nE-mail: " + tEmail.text + "\nPhone: " + tPhone.text;
     lvSend = new LoadVars();
     lvReply = new LoadVars();
     var thanks = "Thanks " + tName.text + "your message has been sent";
     lvSend.msg = sMessage;
     lvSend.address = "myemail@ex.ex";
     tName.text = "";
     tEmail.text = "";
     tPhone.text = "";
     lvReply.onLoad()
     {
        tDone.text = thanks;
     }
     lvSend.sendAndLoad('/templates/t3976/mail.php', lvReply, 'POST');
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it's working :) however in the case of them being empty I would like to write in the "tDone" text field a message "tDone.text = "please fill all of the fields...";" in that case i'll need a hole different function won't I?

Comment: after IF closing bracket "}" add "else{ tDone.text = "form is incomplete"; }"

Comment: Yeah tanks, got it as soon as I posted the comment :)